# How do I stop the creation of a particular object's records from appearing in my chatter feed?

Tags: chatter, filters

I use a rollup app that creates a new rollup queue record every few minutes. Each time one of these records is created, it appears in my chatter feed. Is there a way to filter these out?

I found some salesforce articles about this but I think they are out of date as the steps they suggest are not available.

FYI I am have administrator privileges.

Answer (score 2):

Disable chatter feed for that object fields and its related records.

The below screen shot should help you fix .

[image]

[image]

Disabling checkboxes should help you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mohith. I tried that but it still keeps appearing in my feed every time a record is created. Do you know anywhere else that a setting might be causing this?

Comment: If its diabled for object then it cannot create the feed

Comment: As I said, it is already disabled.

I figured out that the "All Related Objects" check box under User in Feed Tracking is what is causing the record creation to appear in my feed, despite the specific object's tracking being disabled.

Comment: Ben I had indicated the same in my answer